# Data to create account in Magento are not saved to the client panel

Tags: magento

When I'm creating an account on magento some of the data as inputs (taxvat) ('Zip / Postal Code) and (State / Province) are not saved to the client's account panel is not saved in backend customer. The official files is register.phml the customer theme / default / template / customer / form
Use the 1.9.2.2 version of magento believe that this problem runs other versions as well. I do not understand why this not saving the data someone has been there and has a solution.

Comment: Are you debugging Magento or writing your own code?

Answer (score 1):

Rename register.phtml file and let magento use base theme register.phtml file. It might be the case the theme you are using have some issues. If the methods works check for form key in theme register file